# Saving image captured from camera to file in android

Tags: android

Hi In my app I am trying to take a picture from camera and store that image in a file object. For that I am writing the file to external storage but when I try to retrieve the file I am getting filenotfound exception. Please help me. Here is the code I used to save to file.

Environment.getExternalStorageState();

```
           File mediaStorageDir = new File(getCacheDir(),"AppName");

           //mediaStorageDir.mkdir();
           System.out.println("directory path "+mediaStorageDir.getPath());
           if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
               mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
                if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                    Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");

                }
            }

           File   mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_"+ "mypic" + ".jpg");
```

Comment: I think `getCacheDir()` does not get along with Camera App!

Answer (score 0):

Try add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to AndroidManifest

Comment: I have added that permission, but I can't understand how to save the image captured from camera or how to give that image to file object??

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using cache dir instead of external storage? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()

"Returns the absolute path to the application specific cache directory on the filesystem. These files will be ones that get deleted first when the device runs low on storage. There is no guarantee when these files will be deleted."

You should instead use :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

Comment: I tried using  
storageDir = new File(
    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"app");

Comment: And you added the use permission for external storage? Any error in logcat at run time?

Comment: Ya I have added that permission. In logcat I am getting FILENOTFOUND EXCEPTION